# Website keep all static strings in one file

Tags: django, static

I am wondering is there a good way to store all static strings in one(maybe several) file. And then just refer to them from other files(also repeatedly). And in case of editing just change the main string. I think this is a very useful way to reduce the time to make changes.

Comment: Maybe create a dict in your views file and pass it to every template as context?

Comment: @BadredineKheddaoui , yep, I think this what I was need, thx)